# Silent install of an msi in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, windows-installer

How do i install an msi silently using python script? I tried using the below script and it did not work for me!I need to install an msi silently(without showing any UI) and launch the .exe created.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(msiexec /i "D:\mypath\to\.msi" /qn TARGETDIR="D:\msi" ALLUSERS=1)
```

The msiexec is not executing in the command line as well!I am using python 2.7 and windows 7 64-bit system.

Comment: Aramanethota: It is found that the issue is with the admin privilages.How can i run above script as an administrator? - Start with admin previleges. Other options are there but I do not know.